# Is possible use an external 'model-config.json' file at Strongloop

Tags: models, loopbackjs, strongloop

Actually, Strongloop allows developers to use default file for `model-config.json`. Inside it, there is a plenty of model definitions.

Why would I use an external `model-config.json`?

Because, I have a few projects sharing same models. Currently I am able to point models to an parent folder, this way:

**'model-config.json'**

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../../shared-models-project/common/models", // this is external to the project
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ], ... 
}
```

But after doing this change, I noticed that all models are also referenced in `model-config.json` file. Then the solution could be using an external `model-config.json`, located at `shared-models-project/server/model-config.json` instead of `./server/model-config.json`.

**But... is this possible?** Any alternatives??

Answer (score 1):

Loopback will also look for `model-config.js` ([link](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration)), so you could create that file with something like:

`module.exports = require('../../shared-models-project/server/model-config.json')`

Is that what you meant?